# IIS7 URL Filtering

Tags: asp.net, security, iis-7

I'm trying to denied access to my website when users use a URL like

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/./somepage.aspx
```

Right now when I try the url above IIS7 will serve:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/somepage.aspx
```

I also installed urlscan on the server with

```
AllowDotInPath=0

[DenyUrlSequences]

..  ; Don't allow directory traversals
./  ; Don't allow trailing dot on a directory name
\   ; Don't allow backslashes in URL
:   ; Don't allow alternate stream access
%   ; Don't allow escaping after normalization
&   ; Don't allow multiple CGI processes to run on a single request
```

but it still allowing access :(

My way of testing it is using curl:

```
curl -I https://www.mywebsite.com/./somepage.aspx
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advances!

Answer (score 0):

Set your web.config to deny access to all users for somepage.aspx and then allow only authorised users. This is done differently depending on whether you are using Windows Active Directory authorization or form authorization, but the concept is still the same.

On how to set the web.config, [look here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx)

On another note, why do you have a period in your url? is it for a current directory???

Comment: The period in the url is not part of any directory, I just trying to tighten the security in my website, so when someone try to reach https://www.mywebsite.com/./somepage.aspx (should give a forbidden status or not found) the server will do somewhat of url rewrite to https://www.mywebsite.com/somepage.aspx (to the actual page)

Comment: I do user restriction operation inside my web.config. Look at the link i provided, see if it helps you getting what you need. IF a user tries to access restricted webpage, you can set your web.config to redirect to another site showing a more user friendly message.

Comment: I'm not trying to deny access to the page, i just trying to enforces using the correct url instead of funny url like http://www.mywebsite.com/./somepage.aspx

Comment: Sorry, if I miss-understood. I am not sure if you looked at [this page](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/denyUrlSequences) yet.   If not, then it will show how to set deny URL in different levels.    EDIT: [URL Filtering From IIS](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/501/iis-request-filtering-and-url-rewriting/)

Comment: Yeap, i already looked at that site, tried some of those on the web.config but it still allowing access

Comment: Ok, i tried bunch of stuff and did some digging, it seem like you need to use appcmd.exe to put the config through. (I tried the web.config way to no success). And MSDN documentation all points to using the following command  `appcmd set config /section:requestfiltering /+denyurlsequences.[sequence='..']` NOTE: I currently have no access to a IIS server to try it out. So not sure if it will work